# Silverlight ComboBox: Make Selected item Bold?

Tags: silverlight, xaml, combobox, silverlight-4.0

I would like to be able to make the selected item in a Silverlight [`ComboBox`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.combobox(VS.95).aspx) appear in **bold** -- what's the best way to go about doing this?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set a style for ItemContainerStyle for `TargetType="ComboBoxItem"` and include a storyboard for the Selected VisualState.

[Default Styles for a ComboBox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd334408(VS.95).aspx)

You should be able to fairly easily modify these default styles to set an item to bold when it is in the selected state.